# Ansible role_path undefined error

Tags: ansible

I have a task file that looks like this:

```
- name: Drop schemas
  mysql_db: state=import name=mysql target={{ role_path }}/files/schemas/drop-imdb-perf.sql login_user={{ MYSQL_ROOT_USER }} login_password={{ MYSQL_ROOT_PWD }} login_host={{ inventory_hostname }}
```

I'm invoking it from a playbook that looks like this:

```
- name: Drop mySQL data
  gather_facts: no
  hosts: imdb
  connection: local
  tags:
    - mysql-data-drop
  tasks:
    - include: ../roles/mysql/tasks/drop-perf.yml
```

I'm using Ansible version 1.9.4 so I'm thinking `role_path` should be a valid variable.

But when I run the playbook, I get this output:

```
TASK: [Drop schemas] **************************************************
fatal: [imdb] => One or more undefined variables: 'role_path' is undefined
```

I can't figure out why `role_path` is undefined. According to the [ansible docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html), it seems like for versions 1.8 and above it should be populated with the directory of the role in question, but I'm clearly mistaken about something or other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see you using any roles. Without looking into the Ansible code it seems obvious that `role_path` is defined within a role. Including a file of a role does not make it run in context of a role though.

If your include is by intend, `role_path` won't be defined. You could try to set it yourself together with the include like so:

```
tasks:
  - include: ../roles/mysql/tasks/drop-perf.yml
    role_path: ../roles/mysql
```

That might work or not, since `role_path` still is a magic variable and therefore might not be manually changed.

If you actually meant to include the role, then you need to define your playbook like this:

```
- name: Drop mySQL data
  gather_facts: no
  hosts: imdb
  connection: local
  tags:
    - mysql-data-drop
  roles:
    - role: ../roles/mysql
```

But my guess is, you're trying to only run a single tasks file of that role and not the whole role. But what you're trying to do there seem to be against best practice. My recommendation would be to move the tag `mysql-data-drop` into the tasks of the file `drop-perf.yml`, because that's what tags are for: to trigger a limited set of tasks of roles or playbooks.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That makes perfect sense. I'll try to rework it to be more aligned with the ansible best practices. I mostly just did the ol' copy and paste some other stuff that sort of does the same thing, but it shouldn't be too bad to rewrite it the right way.